# Shopping Cart & Shipping Charges

Tags: add-on, shipping, shopping-cart

The website designer we have hired has created our site in Expression Engine and has included a shopping cart to handle donations, registrations and craft shop sales. We are being told that there is no way to automatically calculate shipping charges based on weight and shipping location. They have told us we need to calculate shipping manually for each item. Can you recommend a plug-in or something that can calculate shipping automatically? I can't imagine one doesn't exist that is affordable.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on which add-on was used to provide the ecommerce functionality.

It will most likely be Cartthrob, Expresso Store or Brilliant Retail. If it's a really old and basic site then it might be using SimpleCommerce.

Do any of those names ring a bell?

If you go to the Add-ons->Modules menu do any of those names appear?

Comment: It is using CartThrob.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options for plugins for Cart Throb

**USPS ->** https://github.com/CartThrob/cartthrob-live-rates-UPS/blob/master/cartthrob/third_party/language/english/cartthrob_shipping_ups_lang.php

**FEDEX ->** https://github.com/CartThrob/cartthrob-live-rates-fedex